# Is there a way to get all Memberclasses of a class and loop over them to excecute methods?

Tags: java, class, reflection, class-members

I have an ManagerCLass, which includes many other Objects. Here are methodes, that takes thes Objects and call an method on theses Objects..
Example:

```
public class Manager extends BaseManager {



ClassA classA = new ClassA();
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
ClassC classC = new ClassC();
ClassD classD = new ClassD();
ClassE classE = new ClassE();


public void callMethodsOnObjects() {
    classA.printResult();
    classB.printResult();
    classC.printResult();
    classD.printResult();
    classE.printResult();
}

}
```

These classes have all the same Superclass. Now my Question is, is there a way to automate the callMethodsOnObjects()-method?

My Idea was to get all declaredClasses of the Managerclass. Then to Loop of the array an excecute the printResult()-methode on each Object.

```
Class<?>[] classes = Manager.class.getDeclaredClasses();

    for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        ....
    }
```

But this don´t work. The Array is Empty.

So do you have an Idea if this a way to automate this?
There are still more methods that are structured this way.
I'm not getting anywhere here. Does it make sense to do it this way, as I imagined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the real problem here is that you are using Java terminology incorrectly.

**There are no member classes of the `Manager` class.**  Yup.  That's what I said!

A "member class" is a class that is declared inside another class.  But there aren't any classes declared inside `Manager`.

However, there are fields ("member fields") declared inside `Manager`; i.e. `classA`, `classB` and so on.   And these fields have classes; i.e. `ClassA`, `ClassB` and so on.

If you want to find the member fields of a class, use the `Class.getDeclaredFields()` method.  This will give you an array of `Field` objects.

You can then get each field's class by calling `Field.getType()` on it.  Then you can use reflection to lookup the classses `printResult()` method and invoke it on the value in the respective fields of a target object.

Notes:

1. The `Class` returned by `getType()` *could* denote a primitive type or array type rather than a class.  This `Class` will represent the erased type of the field.
2. If you want the `Type` as it was declared in the source code, use `Field.getGenericType()` instead.